# How can I upload STL files to OctoPrint?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, octoprint, stl

I started playing with OctoPrint and I already have it configured for external access and management, using OctoEverywhere.

I would like it to be an easy to use printer, because it is shared between people that don't use Cura or PrusaSlicer, so I want them to upload STL files and having a slicer built into the print server (printer is an Ender 3) for them to click a button and convert these STL files into a printable G-code. I have tried to add the printer to Cura but it says that the API connection key is invalid. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is exactly the problem with adding your printer in Cura?

Comment: @kosteklvp I have no issues adding it via octopi.local once inside my local network. The problem is I have octoprint running on octoeverywhere and I would like to add it from that link instead of the octopi.local one, for sending the gcode to the printer over the internet instead of limiting to local network devices. When I add the printer in cura by the https://octoeverywhere link, I cannot request an API key from cura neither.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Giving people a bad experience  with 3D printing (for those who it isn't a hobby) is letting them slice their own files... *(from experience, I maintain an Ultimaker printer for a staff association)*. Most users have no clue what a slicer does and how you should place your model and use what settings or materials.

> How can I upload STL files to OctoPrint?

There are a few option from available [plugins](https://plugins.octoprint.org/by_tag/#tag-slicer) to upload and slice STL files, but these options are not powerful enough with respect to desktop standalone slicing application. Furthermore, when there are multiple materials in play, it is best you appoint some trained/experienced users to slice for others. This works very well from experience, it spreads the load over multiple people.

Also, most of the plugin options are not maintained for a while and use old slicing engines. This shouldn't be the way to operate a community printer.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload G-code directly from Cura or PrusaSlicer, but you need to use a [OctoEverywhere Shared Connection](https://octoeverywhere.com/sharredconnection) when you set up your OctoPrint or Klipper instance in Cura.

Here's a [step-by-step guide](https://blog.octoeverywhere.com/cura-everywhere/) on how to set Cura with OctoEverywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Octoprint web UI (as of writing, Version 1.9.3) allows for drag n' drop for file upload.

Slice and export locally, then drag it over to the Web UI, or use the embedded upload button.

Comment: Do you know what the version number is (to save people later having to correlate the date of writing, release dates and versions numbers)? If so, please [edit] your answer and add it there.